# Launch Gulp Watch for JS and detect current folder has changed

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-concat, gulp-livereload

I need to minimize the number of gulp's command from my gulpfile.

This is my JS folders

```
js/
   templates/
              t-01/
              t-02/
              [...]
              t-xxx/
```

My gulp task for JS (with livereload)

```
gulp.task('da-js', function() {
    gulp.src([
        'js/templates/**/*.js',
        '!js/templates/**/*.min.js'
        ])
        .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js/templates'))
        .pipe(livereload());
});
```

This task is global the destination folder is `templates` but I want to detect the current folder of js files like is :

1. I'm changing js in `/templates/t-01/`
2. `gulp.watch` is launching
3. `app.min.js` is generating only in this folder `t-01`

I know the `gulp.dest` is not correct to target current folder but I don't know how to do this.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Are you monitor all files under `templates` folder for updates so that any change in any JS file under this folder should generate your `app.min.js` again ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use gulp's `watch` method to monitor a folder with JS files for updates and run a series of tasks in response to some change.

```
gulp.task('watch-files', function() {
    gulp.watch('js/templates/**/*.js', ['da-js']);
});
```

Here we're watching over all the JS files in templates and all it's sub-folders and running your file concatenation task (`da-js`) for every update. Now that we're executing the same task, your `app.min.js` folder will be generated in your `templates` folder even when you change `templates/t-01/some.js`.

With the `watch-files` task defined in your `gulpfile.js`, you can simply run `gulp watch-files` command which will start monitoring your files.